# What is the proper way to add [ngClass] to host element programmatically if element was created dynamically?

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

I have dynamically created element

```
initElem() {
let childElFactory = this._cfRes.resolveComponentFactory(childElCmp);
// _cfRes is ComponentFactoryResolver
let childElRef = this._vcRef.createComponent(childElFactory);
// _vcRef is ViewContainerRef
childElRef.instance.childElModel = someModel;
}
```

and I want to add

```
[ngClass]="{active: childElModel.active}"
```

attribiute and

```
#childEl
```

attribiute to host element of childElCmp.

I don't want to use elementRef as it's not a proper way.
I think Renderer is what I am looking for but I don't know how to use it in the right way.

Answer (score 5):

You can't apply `[ngClass]...` or any other binding to a dynamically added component.

You can add

```
@HostBinding('class.active') isActive:boolean = false;
```

into your dynamically added component and then use

```
childref.instance.isActive = true;
```

To get the `active` class added/removed from the component.

Or you can inject `ElementRef` into the parent component and use

```
elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('child-el').classList.add('active');
```

Comment: Thanks. @HostBinding is what I was looking for.

Comment: If using object model or array as input of Your component, You also need to extend DoCheck for update your data.

Comment: Is the approach with nativeElement okay? Because I've come to learn that manipulating DOM with `nativeElement` should be considered bad

Comment: It's not really bad by itself. It depends on your requirements. If you want to use server-side rendering or Angulars WebWorker feature, it probably will cause issues, otherwise it's still a good idea to try to avoid accessing members of `nativeElement` if possible just because it's not the way to use Angular. Angular doesn't provide any API to read from the DOM though, and sometimes this is unavoidable, then you'll probably have to access members of `nativeElement`.